# Is [tag:help] helpful?

Tags: discussion, tags

[help](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/help) has collected a lot of junk. I think it would be assumed that (all?) questions are about help/support. Perhaps it's being used when a tag is required and there is no general OS help tab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, the [help](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/help) tag seems like it would be junk. This is a Q&A site, most of them are about needing help.